# encrypt / decrypt record id to 7 char in php

Tags: php

I am uploading files to my server and nameing them with record ID. because record id is in sequence, these files are not safe can be downloaded in loop. http://www.blabla.com/1.jpg .. 2.jpg etc.

I want to encrypt the record id to 7 char and while reading these files I want to dycrypt it back.

so file names would be

http://www.blabla.com/72ayhg6.jpg

which(72ayhg6) is when dycripted is id 1.

How can I do this using php.

Php decrypt and encrypt generate quite a long number. Can I added some sort of salt in it and limited it to 7 or 11 char.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_short_ids_with_php_like_youtube_or_tinyurl/

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need to decrypt it?

Did you bother to read up on anti-leeching strategies.

A simple approach (though far from ideal, since its just security by obscurity) would be to rename the files based on a hash of the record id and a nonce.

> Can I added some sort of salt in it and limited it to 7 or 11 char linux file name limit.

If you don't know the difference between Linux and MS-DOS, perhaps you need to cover some of the basics before attempting to write code?